# Play video with subtitle(SRT file) in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, html5-video, srt

I have video and its srt file, I want to play video with subtitle using Angularjs or some other player. Is there any simple way to achieve this?
I have tried videoSub ( http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/ ) but its working when srt file available in my local path, But i have srt file in server.
Its not working when i use server file

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track But you'll need to convert your srt to VTT

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, Which one is best VTT or SRT?

Comment: For the web, VTT

Comment: Can we use VTT file also in our system players? Like VLC

Comment: Yes VLC does support VTT since 2.2.0 For other players, I'm not sure.

Comment: I have changed to VTT but that file in the storage so it showing cross origin error